# How to do a different action for the last element of a list iterated through map

Tags: reactjs

I am iterating through the whole list of foreignLanguage objects and I want to put a comma and space after every element except the last one.

```
{
    this.state.foreignLanguages.map(foreignLanguage =>
        <>
            {foreignLanguage["name"]},&nbsp;
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about joining the array items instead?

```
{
    this.state.foreignLanguages
      .map(foreignLanguage => foreignLanguage.name)
      .join(', ')
}
```